# What is the default payload for an exploit in Metasploit?

Tags: metasploit

Is there any default payload (if not set explicitly) which gets executed for an exploit in Metasploit?

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found [here](https://metasploit.help.rapid7.com/docs/working-with-payloads):

```
There is a preference list that Metasploit uses to select a payload if there isn't one set for the exploit. Here's the list, sorted by the order in which they will be selected:

    windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
    java/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
    php/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
    php/meterpreter_reverse_tcp
    ruby/shell_reverse_tcp
    cmd/unix/interact
    cmd/unix/reverse
    cmd/unix/reverse_perl
    cmd/unix/reverse_netcat_gaping
    windows/meterpreter/reverse_nonx_tcp
    windows/meterpreter/reverse_ord_tcp
    windows/shell/reverse_tcp
    generic/shell_reverse_tcp
```